# How do I route audio output to a selected audio endpoint/device in Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, uwp, media-player, playback

TL;DR: When playing audio using Windows UWP MediaPlayer, how do I route audio to a specific audio device/endpoint?

## Full Context

I'm working on an app to place calls. Some requirements are:

- Play audio sounds at different points (e.g. when the call hangs up)
- Allow users to change in-call audio output to different endpoints (not an issue)
- Ensure that when in-call audio has routed to a different "default" endpoint, that any other sounds that are played are routed to the same endpoint (*this is what I need help with*)

Currently, when I route audio to a different endpoint, other sounds that are played with Windows UWP MediaPlayer do not get routed to the same "new" endpoint. This makes sense since we aren't changing application-wide settings.

**My question is:** How do I route audio to the *same* endpoint that the call audio is going through, given that I'm using Windows UWP MediaPlayer and given that I can get device information?

Comment: Does the following work, and do you have any updates?

Answer (score 1):

> When playing audio using Windows UWP MediaPlayer, how do I route audio to a specific audio device/endpoint?

Please check [**Output to a specific audio endpoint**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer#output-to-a-specific-audio-endpoint) document. *By default, the audio output from a MediaPlayer is routed to the default audio endpoint for the system, but you can specify a specific audio endpoint that the MediaPlayer should use for output.*
You could use [`GetAudioRenderSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.devices.mediadevice.getaudiorenderselector?view=winrt-19041) to get the render selector then use `FindAllAsync` to get render device the pass the specific device  to mediaplayer [`AudioDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.audiodevice?view=winrt-19041) property.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work in my case because in-call audio uses MMDevice APIs and the sound player uses UWP MediaPlayer. The device IDs are different between the two I think? Which means I would have to standardize on MMDevice APIs and use win32 APIs...unless I'm missing something.